# Android - Changing variables in a formula dynamically

Tags: android, reference, formula, dynamic-variables

I'm stuck at a point that seems simple and likely there's an easy way to deal with it, but I need help anyway.

I need to evaluate a formula using a set of constants, that should be chosen dynamically depending on the selection of the user. See the code:

```
double constOne=2.3, constTwo=1.1, constThree=1.7...; //and so on

public double doSomething(int inputOne, String selection){

    //being const... one of the double vars defined above, 
    //selected based on the String selection
    return inputOne*const...; 
}
```

I know I can do this using an array of doubles and passing to doSomething() the position on the array, but that's very hardcoded and really I prefer not to do it that way.

Is there a way to reference to the constOne, constTwo, etc. dynamically? Thanks!

PS: yes, I know could be a silly question, I'm learning!

Comment: Unless the constants need to be here, why don't you pass a double to the function with the other params?

Comment: How about using a Map? Do you see some problem with that? It seems to be the perfect solution, but makes me wonder why I didn't find that solution before.

Comment: I think it would probably work but I'm not sure it is necessary. It think the answer given by Ahmed or my suggestion might be cleaner and/or easier. But you could try and see if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see the problem of declaring the constants in an array.

However if you are really against that you can write a helper function which will take in the selector String and return the constant. This could make your code cleaner

```
double getConstant(String selector) {
    // some logic
}
```

Then your other function would be a bit cleaner

```
public double doSomething(int inputOne, String selection){

    //being const... one of the double vars defined above, 
    //selected based on the String selection
    return inputOne * getConstant(selection); 
}
```

The benefit of doing it this way would be your logic for selecting a constant from a selector would be in one place rather than in all functions where you need the constants.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, it seems to be the best option. A Map/HashMap would solve that the problem too, but it's like killing flies with a shotgun.

Another solution would be to use an array, but I didn't want to do it that way because I should think all the time on the index/content correlation, which makes the code harder to maintain and also hard to debug.

Thanks!